# Post request in JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors, box-api

Hello i am using box api to for integration they have given just curl to get access token
which is as follow

```
curl https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token \
-d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code={your_code}&client_id={your_client_id}&client_secret={your_client_secret}' \
-X POST
```

I want to get access token using jquery ajax request i have tired my code like this as follow :

```
var data2= '{"grant_type":"authorization_code", "client_id":"READACTED" ,"client_secret":"Redacted" ,"code" :"'+code+'"}';
var data1 = JSON.parse(data2);

$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url:  "https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token",
                    data: data1,
                    success: function(json) {
                        console.log(e);
                       alert("success"+json);
                    },
                    error: function(e) {
                        console.log(e)
                        alert("Failure"+ JSON.stringify(e));

                    }
                });
```

I am facing problem with this request as it gives me error in browser console :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

please tell me where i am wrong it is working fine with Postman client .

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What have you tried?

Comment: @RocketHazmat please check now i have mention more detail

Comment: You're being blocked by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).  You can't access the box.com API directly from JavaScript.

Comment: what should i do now >

Comment: You need to create a script on your server to contact the API and then make your AJAX call point to that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get past the same-origin policy, you'll need to contact Box support team.  You can  either email api@box.com or follow the "Box Community" link on the Box webpage in the lower right side.

The support team will ask you for the origin URL or URLs that you want to use (Box does not allow wildcard origins) in the CORS header.  They will also need to know your application name, or API Key to lookup your app and setup your CORS headers for you.